# Does JAVA is a correct choice for Online Conference System (Audio/video)?

Tags: java, project, voip, jmf

I am doing a project on a **Online Conference System (Stand-alone Desktop application)**. For this I have choose **JAVA** as language.When I want to open capture devices using **JMF** some time it cannot gives exception

> "Cannot initialize capture device".

I search for this problem,many users are facing this problem. For this, i am thinking that

Am I take correct decision by taking JAVA???

Comment: Java is not an acronym. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access web Cams, Java might not be the solution. Most of the Java WebCam libraries are down, JMF as well, it is outdated.

You might find other libraries like FMJ which were famous few years back, but they are outdated as well.

The only library I know which is not outdated is **Xuggler** . **VLCJ** also seems to be outdated, but some claims it works with majority of web cams.

If you need only audio/video streaming then JavaFX might help. http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/media/overview.htm

The other BEST library for this is **JavaCV** which I can guaranty. But the case is it is a wrapper for C++ OpenCV, so you need to do lot of work there, to make it work with Java. And, it has no or less documentation at the moment.